# Multipart form Response from NodeJS Server- issue extracting some fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, multipartform-data

I have a ReactJS Application that sends an Axios POST request to a NodeJS express server and expects a response with several fields. Specifically, I am using "form-data" in the backend to handle the data streaming.

Here is my backend response.

```
var FormData = require('form-data');

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    // create a new form to send all data back to client
    var form = new FormData();

    form.append('results_log', 'this is text', { contentType: 'text/plain'});
    form.append('results_images', fs.createReadStream('./test_results/result.zip'), { contentType: 'application/zip' });

    console.log(form);

    form.pipe(res);
});
```

In the frontend, I can download the "results_images" ZIP file from the formdata server response without any issues, but I cannot get the "results_log" field, which is just a simple string. Every attempt has resulted in a "null".

Below is the frontend code.

```
axios({
            url: 'http://localhost:5000/test',
            method: 'GET'
        })
            .then((response) => {
                var info = response;

                // this alerts NULL
                alert(info.data["results_log"]);

                const url = window.URL
                    .createObjectURL(new Blob([info.data["results_images"]]));


                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = url;
                link.setAttribute('download', 'results.zip');
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Here is part of the alert of the whole response.data field. As you can see, both fields are present in the response.

Am I doing something wrong when extracting the string field? Any help is appreciated!

[image]